# Outputting data from JSON to Telegram

Tags: python, json, parsing, telegram-bot, aiogram

Good afternoon, I made a bot by example, reworking it for myself. The bottom line is that I receive data from the site using parsing, then write the data to JSON, and then output this data to telegrams. Here is the problem with the last stage, I cannot understand why the data is displayed in the tagaz. An example in the picture. Please tell me how to fix it.

Here is my code:

bot.py --- This is the bot code

```
import asyncio
import datetime
import json
from os import name
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.utils.markdown import hbold, hunderline, hcode, hlink
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardRemove, \
    ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, \
    InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from conf import TOKEN, user_id
from main import check_news_update
from people import data_bth

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# Создание кнопок меню --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


button1 = KeyboardButton('Дні народження')
button2 = KeyboardButton('Новини')
button3 = KeyboardButton('3️⃣')
button4 = KeyboardButton('4️⃣')


# Инициализация кнопок ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


menu_razmetka = ReplyKeyboardMarkup().row(
    button1, button2
)

menu_razmetka.row(button3, button4)


# Создание кнопок инлайн --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


inline_btn_1 = InlineKeyboardButton('Сьогодні', callback_data='btn1')
inline_btn_2 = InlineKeyboardButton('На неділі', callback_data='btn2')
inline_btn_3 = InlineKeyboardButton('У цьому місяці', callback_data='btn3')

inline_btn_4 = InlineKeyboardButton('Останні 3 новини', callback_data='btn4')
inline_btn_5 = InlineKeyboardButton('Свіжі новини', callback_data='btn5')


# Инициализация кнопок(инлайн) ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


inline_button_menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2).add(
    inline_btn_1).add(inline_btn_2).add(inline_btn_3)

inline_button_menu_2 = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2).add(
    inline_btn_4).add(inline_btn_5)


# Кнопка старт --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])  # --- кнопка старт при старте бота
async def start_bot(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Вітаю {0.first_name}!\nЛаскаво просимо в офіційний чат 
    бот\nБердянської міської ради\n\nЯкщо ви загубилися в боті, використовуйте - /help\n\nЯкщо у 
    Вас виникнуть проблеми з ботом, використовуйте - /admin\n\nВиклик головного меню - 
    /menu".format(message.from_user), reply_markup=menu_razmetka)


# Кнопки меню рядом с текстом -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

@dp.message_handler(commands=['menu'])
async def main_menu(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Меню", reply_markup=menu_razmetka)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['help'])
async def help_menu(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Ви можете керувати мною, надсилаючи такі команди:\n\n/start - головне 
меню бота\n/admin - зв'язок з техпідтримкою бота\n")

@dp.message_handler(commands=['admin'])
async def admin_menu(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Техпідтримка  контакти:\nTelegram: admin\nPhone: 
+380996855571\nGmail: admin.gmail.com")


# Кнопки меню(инлайн) ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

@dp.message_handler()
async def on_message(message: types.Message):
    # await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, message.text)
    if message.text == 'Дні народження':
        await message.reply("Виберіть як подивитися дні народження: ", 
reply_markup=inline_button_menu)
    elif message.text == 'Новини':
        await message.reply("Виберіть як подивитися новини: ", 
reply_markup=inline_button_menu_2)

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'btn4') # --- Последние три новости
async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    with open("news_dict.json") as file:
        news_dict = json.load(file)

    for k, v in sorted(news_dict.items())[-3:]:
        news = f"{hlink(v['article_title'], v['article_url'])}"

        await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, news)

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'btn5') # --- Свежие новости
async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    fresh_news = check_news_update()

    if len(fresh_news) >= 1:
        for k, v in sorted(fresh_news.items()):
            news = f"{(v['article_title'], v['article_url'])}"

            await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, news)

    else:
        await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, 'Свіжих новин немає')


# Полигон -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # loop.create_task(news_every_minute())
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

main.py --- This is the code of the parser and writing to JSON

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



# --- NEW VOKEBLULARY ---------------------------------------------------------------- NEW 
VOKEBLULARY --------------------

def get_first_news():
    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36 Edg/91.0.864.64"
    }

    url = "https://bmr.gov.ua/index.php?id=2&no_cache=1"
    r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    articles_cards = soup.find_all("div", class_="article articletype-0")

    news_dict = {}
    for article in articles_cards:
        article_title = article.find("h3").text.strip()
        article_desc = article.find("p").text.strip()

        for i in article.find_all('a', class_='more', href=True):    
            article_url = (f'https://bmr.gov.ua/{i["href"]}')
            article_id = article_url.split("/")[-1]

            news_dict[article_id] = {
                "article_title": article_title,
                "article_url": article_url,
                "article_desc": article_desc}

    with open("news_dict.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(news_dict, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)

# --- UPDATE VOCABULARY ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
UPDATE VOCABULARY ------------

def check_news_update():
    with open("news_dict.json") as file:
        news_dict = json.load(file)

    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36 Edg/91.0.864.64"
    }

    url = "https://bmr.gov.ua/"
    r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
    articles_cards = soup.find_all("div", class_="article articletype-0")



    fresh_news = {}
    for article in articles_cards:

        for i in article.find_all('a', class_='more', href=True):    
            article_url = (f'https://bmr.gov.ua/{i["href"]}')
            article_id = article_url.split("/")[-1]

        if article_id in news_dict:
            continue
        else:
            article_title = article.find("h3").text.strip()
            article_desc = article.find("p").text.strip()

            news_dict[article_id] = {
                "article_title": article_title,
                "article_url": article_url,
                "article_desc": article_desc
            }

            fresh_news[article_id] = {
                "article_title": article_title,
                "article_url": article_url,
                "article_desc": article_desc
            }

    with open("news_dict.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(news_dict, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)

    return fresh_news


# --- START -------------------------------------------------------------------------- START ---------

def main():
    # get_first_news()
    print(check_news_update())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here's the result:

[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QtS1.png)

Comment: what do you have in JSON? Show it in question, not in comment.

Comment: I see you use `hlink` and it may add `tag`. But I don't understand why you run `hlink` inside `f"{..}"` if you should use directly `news = hlink(...)`

Comment: I removed hlink and now everything is fine, thanks)